# Use Input class in Laravel Blade file

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 7.28.3. I am trying to use `Input` class in Blade file like below.

```
{{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('placeholder' => 'awesome@awesome.com')) }}
```

I used `'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,` in `aliases` array in `app.php`

But I am getting below error.

`Class 'Input' not found`

Comment: ```php artisan config:cache```

Comment: Go to `app\config\app.php` and add the line in the ``aliases`` as `'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,` and then save and retry . Sometimes this will be the issue.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenClarin. Your solution is not working.

Comment: Thanks @kaviranga. Your solution is not working.

Comment: @abuabu `Input` class better works with `laravel 5` . I'm not tested it on `laravel 7`.

Comment: laravel collective automatically supports old input value. and in case you need specifically use the `old()` helper method. Input class has been deprecated.